# JQuery Show() all properties

Tags: jquery

By default if you specify a speed jQuery adds a weird looking animation where it expands from the left end corner. I want it to just slide down. Is there a way to do that without importing something else like jQuery UI?

Comment: Can you share some code with us to see what you are currently doing? An easy solution to me sounds like using the `slideDown()` function...

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.next').click(function (event) {
         $divId=event.target.id;
         $('#div-'+$divId).hide(700,'swing');
         $('#div-'+$divId).next().show(1000,'swing');
      });
      $('.back').click(function (event) {
         $divId=event.target.id;
         $('#div-'+$divId).hide(700,'swing');
         $('#div-'+$divId).prev().show(1000,'swing');

      });

Comment: You should edit your post and add it there properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $( "#yourId" ).slideDown( "slow", function() {
    // Animation complete.
 });
```

Or

```
$( "#yourId" ).slideDown( "slow" );
```

Or even just

```
$( "#yourId" ).slideDown();
```

Look at

http://api.jquery.com/slidedown/

Comment: This is the correct answer.  JSFiddle showing example: https://jsfiddle.net/93dac06c/